# What is the best way to transform spaces between words into + sign?

Tags: javascript, regex

The function should transform input value to query:

```
1. "   bald   valves  " to "bald+valves"
2. " buffers some  " to "buffers+some"
```

that is my current solution:

```
query.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(/[\s.;,?%]/, '+')
```

could you please help me to improve it?

Comment: How exactly do you need it improved? Questions about improving working code should be asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: You can improve by making it `replace(/\s+/g, ' +')`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
s.trim().replace(/\s+/g,'+')

"   bald   valves  ".trim().replace(/\s+/g,'+')
"bald+valves"
" buffers some  ".trim().replace(/\s+/g,'+')
"buffers+some"
```